# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I am getting the following error whenever a page gets rendered,

```
    <Jul 23, 2014 7:05:14 PM GMT+05:30> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101362> <[ServletContext@1791852040[app:BANCS-ONLINE module:CommonWeb path:null spec-version:3.0]] could not deserialize the request scoped attribute with name: "org.apache.myfaces.COMPONENT_STACK"
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1190)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:163)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1709)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have checked the call stack of the exception by debuging it. Here it is,

```
Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Suspended (exception NotSerializableException)) 
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeObject0(Object, boolean) line: 1190   
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeArray(Object, ObjectStreamClass, boolean) line: 1384  
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeObject0(Object, boolean) line: 1180   
    ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream, Object, boolean) line: 163    
    ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields() line: 1709    
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeFields() line: 485    
    Stack<E>(Vector<E>).writeObject(ObjectOutputStream) line: 1073  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 76  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 607  
    ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Object, ObjectOutputStream) line: 1049  
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeSerialData(Object, ObjectStreamClass) line: 1502  
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeOrdinaryObject(Object, ObjectStreamClass, boolean) line: 1438 
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeObject0(Object, boolean) line: 1184   
    WLObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream).writeObject(Object) line: 353  
    PassivationUtils.toByteArray(Object, Replacer) line: 33 
    PassivationUtils.toByteArray(Object) line: 24   
    PassivationUtils.copy(Object) line: 64  
    AttributeWrapper.getObject(boolean, WebAppServletContext) line: 97  
    AttributeWrapper.getObject(WebAppServletContext) line: 65   
    AttributesMap.get(String, WebAppServletContext) line: 108   
    ServletRequestImpl.getAttribute(String) line: 773   
    RequestEventsFilter$EventsRequestWrapper(ServletRequestWrapper).getAttribute(String) line: 116  
    WebappLifecycleListener.requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent) line: 118 
    ConfigureListener.requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent) line: 366   
    EventsManager.notifyRequestLifetimeEvent(ServletRequest, boolean) line: 389 
    RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 30 
    FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 74  
    RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(boolean, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, ServletResponseImpl, int) line: 565   
    RequestDispatcherImpl.include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 471    
    ImportTag(ImportSupport).acquireString() line: 327  
    ImportTag(ImportSupport).doEndTag() line: 184   
    policyPartySearch.jsp line: 32  
    policyPartySearch.jsp line: 31  
    policyPartySearch.jsp line: 30  
    policyPartySearch.jsp line: 29  
    __policypartysearch(JspBase).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 34  
    StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run() line: 242 
    StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run() line: 216 
    StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(ServletRequest, HttpServletRequest, ServletRequestImpl, ServletResponse, HttpServletResponse, Servlet) line: 132   
    JavelinxJSPStub(ServletStubImpl).execute(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChainImpl) line: 338    
    JavelinxJSPStub(ServletStubImpl).execute(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 221 
    RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(boolean, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, ServletResponseImpl, int) line: 564   
    RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 263    
    ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(String) line: 369   
    JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FacesContext, UIViewRoot) line: 99 
    RenderResponseExecutor.execute(FacesContext) line: 78   
    LifecycleImpl.render(FacesContext) line: 241    
    FacesServlet.service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 199 
    StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run() line: 242 
    StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run() line: 216 
    StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(ServletRequest, HttpServletRequest, ServletRequestImpl, ServletResponse, HttpServletResponse, Servlet) line: 132   
    ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChainImpl) line: 338 
    TailFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 25  
    FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 74  
    ApplicationFilter.doFilter(FilterChain, ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 802  
    ApplicationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 422  
    FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 74  
    RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 27 
    FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 74  
    WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(ServletStub, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 3296   
    WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run() line: 3262   
    AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AbstractSubject, PrivilegedAction) line: 321  
    SecurityManager.runAs(AuthenticatedSubject, AuthenticatedSubject, PrivilegedAction) line: 120   
    WlsSubjectHandle.run(PrivilegedAction) line: 57 
    WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(ServletInvocationContext, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean, boolean) line: 2171   
    WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean) line: 2097    
    WebAppServletContext.execute(ServletRequestImpl, ServletResponseImpl) line: 2075    
    ServletRequestImpl.run() line: 1514 
    ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run() line: 254 
    ExecuteThread.execute(Runnable) line: 256   
    ExecuteThread.run() line: 221
```

Moreover I am using `myfaces 2.1.15` in my WebApp lib and deploying it in `Weblogic 12c`.
My bean is in request scope and `org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION` is set to false. I am not sure why JSF is trying to Serialize-deserialize the properties.

Can anyone please help me out in this. I am really stuck on this now.
Please comment if you need more info of my webApp.

Comment: Anybody have any answer of this issue, please comment on this. I need to resolve it quickly.